# Program can't return True only False

Tags: python

I have the following problem from [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/):

> You live in the city of Cartesia where all roads are laid out in a perfect grid. You arrived ten minutes too early to an appointment, so you decided to take the opportunity to go for a short walk. The city provides its citizens with a Walk Generating App on their phones -- everytime you press the button it sends you an array of one-letter strings representing directions to walk (eg. `['n', 's', 'w', 'e']`). You always walk only a single block for each letter (direction) and you know it takes you one minute to traverse one city block, so create a function that will return true if the walk the app gives you will take you exactly ten minutes (you don't want to be early or late!) and will, of course, return you to your starting point. Return false otherwise.

The input `['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']` should return `True`, but my following solution returns `None`:

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
if not len(walk) == 10:
    return False

elif 'n' in walk:
    if not 's' in walk:
        return False
    elif not walk.count('n') == walk.count('s'):
        return False

elif 's' in walk:
    if not 'n' in walk:
        return False

elif 'e' in walk:
    if not 'w' in walk:
        return False
    elif not walk.count('e') == walk.count('w'):
        return False

elif 'w' in walk:
    if not 'e' in walk:
        return False

else:
    return True
```

Comment: Try deleting the "else" part. So at the end of the function theres just return True

Comment: You don't have an `else` for any of your inner if/elif chains.

Comment: I get the feeling you don't really understand what `else` or the `el` in `elif` means. You seem to be expecting all of your `else` and `elif` blocks to execute regardless of whether the previous `if` or `elif` executes. An `if`/`elif` chain stops immediately at the first test that passes - it doesn't execute any further `elif` tests or an `else` block if it hits a passing test.

Comment: Your code has obvious indentation errors, but it's less obvious what the correct indentation should be. Your problem statement should contain valid Python in order for us to analyze it. Please [edit] to fix this error (on the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select it and type ctrl-K.)

Answer (score 0):

Please test the below code.

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
    if not len(walk) == 10:
        return False
    elif 'n' in walk:
        if walk.count('n') == walk.count('s'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif 's' in walk:
        if walk.count('s') == walk.count('n'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif 'e' in walk:
        if walk.count('e') == walk.count('w'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif 'w' in walk:
        if walk.count('w') == walk.count('e'):
            return True
        else:
            return False

        

walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's']
print(is_valid_walk(walk))
```

Comment: I tested the above code and it returns True as you expected.